# create sales template

Tags: template, automated-process

I received this inquiry from the Sales team.
Is this possible? From my understanding, it is not possible, but a second opinion would be helpful.

> I wanted to create sales templates to automatically populate the
> contact info.
>
> Am I able to do this through salesforce and outlook and share it with
> my team?

Comment: Which one you pointed here as Contact info..Is it Salesforce's Contact record information or outlook contacts (org contacts)?

Comment: Yes, its Salesforce Contact record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can able to create Custom Email Templates in Salesforce org.

Please go to **Setup >> Quick Find >> Classic Email Templates**

You can refer this [document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_emailtemplates.htm&type=5) which help you in detail about classic email template.

During Email template body designing process, you can able to insert the Contact record Information by using the option "Merge field". Which is used to fetch the Contact record field information into your email body

[image]

Then you can use that email template in any Email Alert and after you can use that email alert in any Email Sending functionalities like Workflow, Flow, Process Builder and Trigger based on Contact creation/update action.

Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In lightning you (or any user) can create custom email templates with mail merge fields:

[image: Screenshot of email with merge fields]